# Programmatically select Segment index

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an outlet titled "segmentSection" and I can't set a default selected index value.

What I have tried should work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentSection: UISegmentedControl!
segmentSection.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
```

the goal of this code is to produce a selected state on the index indicated above.

Comment: where do you set the segment index?

Comment: "segmentSection.selectedSegmentIndex = 0"

Comment: I meant where in the code of the view controller? this should be executed in viewDidLoad

Comment: You're right. This *should* work. A few things I'd check.... (1) Is the `IBOutlet` connected? (2) Can you give use more code? At least enough to actually duplicate your issue? Many time a request like this will help you help yourself. **BTW**, and not directed to you - this **STUPID** April Fools joke is really backfiring - PLEASE PEOPLE, make it **simple** to **turn this off**.

Comment: yeah that's where it's located. Maybe it needs another command to highlight it to show it is selected?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    segmentSection.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}
```

You need to put it somewhere useful.

Comment: I have it located exactly as you do. I'm starting to think maybe it is selected but not showing as selected? Is there some sort of background colour/tint/highlight command aswell?

Comment: Why don't you just show all the relevant code? There is obviously a typo somewhere.

Comment: literally just didn't include it was in viewDidLoad